# How to exclude columns which contain certain characters in SQL (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

As the title states, I am trying to exclude any department which name starts on S therefore sales and shipping. This is my current code

```
SELECT department.department_name AS "Department Name",
    location.city AS "CITY",
COUNT(department.department_name) AS "Workers"
FROM DEPARTMENT
JOIN EMPLOYEE USING (department_id)
JOIN LOCATION USING (location_id)
group by department.department_name, location.city
HAVING COUNT(department.department_name) >= 3
ORDER BY department.department_name ASC;
```

[image: Current Output]

Answer (score 1):

You can add this WHERE condition:

```
where department.department_name not like 'S%'
```